# Ifnull not working as expected in splunk query

Tags: splunk-query

I have a column returning null values occasionally, so I used IFNULL to replace null with 0. It does replace null with 0, but the problem is that it is also replacing any non-null values with 0.

index = “test” service=“jenkins”
| eval devices_available = IFNULL((metrics.devices),0)
| table start, end, devices_available

Looking for help to see why this is not working. Thanks!